# Convergence of $\int_1^\infty \frac{dt}{t^4+t^2+1}$

Tags: integration, limits, convergence-divergence

I have to calculate $\displaystyle\int_1^\infty \frac{dt}{t^4+t^2+1}$ and i have as a hint:
Divide by $t^2+t+1$
Then I get that $(t^2+t+1)(t^2-t+1)= t^4+t^2+1$
I could do this by partial fractions but it would be tedious...
Is there any other way that I am not seeing?

Comment: What limit ? There is no limit in your formula.

Comment: What do you mean? Doesnt that converges?

Comment: $\int_1^{\infty}{\frac{dt}{t^4+t^2+1}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}{\int_1^{x}{\frac{dt}{t^4+t^2+1}}}$, so that's why Yves (correctly) says there is no limit in $\int_1^{\infty}{\frac{dt}{t^4+t^2+1}}$ and maybe it's also why you were confused by his comment. It does converge btw.

Comment: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^{n}\frac{1}{t^4+t^2+1}\space\text{d}t=\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}-3\ln(3)}{12}$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT:
Notice, $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{dt}{t^4+t^2+1}=\lim_{z\to \infty}\int_{1}^{z}\frac{dt}{t^4+t^2+1}$$
$$=\lim_{z\to \infty}\int_{1}^{z}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{t^2}\right)dt}{t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}+1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{z\to \infty}\int_{1}^{z}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)-\left(1-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)}{t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}+1}\ dt$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{z\to \infty}\left(\int_{1}^{z}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)dt}{t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}+1}\ dt-\int_{1}^{z}\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)dt}{t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}+1}\ dt\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{z\to \infty}\left(\int_{1}^{z}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{t^2}\right)dt}{\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)^2+3}\ dt-\int_{1}^{z}\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)dt}{\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)^2-1}\ dt\right)$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{z\to \infty}\left(\int_{1}^{z}\frac{d\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)}{\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)^2+(\sqrt{3})^2}\ dt-\int_{1}^{z}\frac{d\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)}{\left(t+\frac{1}{t}\right)^2-(1)^2}\ \right)$$
I hope you can take it from here

Comment: Thanks, i guess there are no shortcuts for this int...

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**:

Do decompose the fraction using the given factorization. You will get two fractions with a first degree numerator and second degree denominator.

By adding a suitable constant to the numerator, you will turn it to the derivative of the denominator, making the fractions easy.

Then you need to compensate with two integrands of the form

$$\frac 1{t^2\pm t+1}.$$

By a simple shift of the variable, you transform this into

$$\frac1{t^2+c},$$

which gives an $\arctan$ or $\text{artanh}$ depending on the sign of $c$.

Comment: I don't think there is a shortcut.